# Javascript - What kind of javascript class that use in this code?

Tags: javascript

I have found a [JavaScript gallery](http://www.photoswipe.com/).

When I view the JavaScript code, I really don't understand how to write code in this style. What is the style called? Where can I find documents related to it?

Note: what i want to know is the way that define Class in this code

(function (){ ... })(window)

what is style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com)

  Based on your question, it seems you're not familiar with jQuery.  jQuery is a JavaScript framework written in JavaScript.  It is most useful for it's selector/filter capabilities, being able to pull objects of objects using something like `$('div');` (or `jQuery('div');`), which would pull all the `div`s from the page.  Using dot notation, you can perform methods on those returned objects.
- `(function (){ ... })(window)`...

  is both an unnamed function definition and call, passing in the `window` object.  It's sort of like `function foo (){...} foo(window)`, only you don't store the definition in variable `foo` and you need to wrap the definition in parentheses for syntax recognition in order to call it with the trailing parentheses.

For more advanced JavaScript topics, google `closure`s.

Comment: thank , to know more about (function (){ ... })(window)... i can search with keyword : closures ?

Comment: Chameron, there's not much to learn about that, it's just a self-contained definition and call; basically a function w/o creating a variable.  Closures are a similar, but different subject.  They are many times stored into a variable, but their uses/impacts have sort of been a new exciting topic these past couple of years.

Comment: i don't know about unnamed function . http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ thank you for explaining me :D

Comment: correct.  you'll find there are a lot of interchanged terminology floating around, function expression will provide the most hit.  I'm not sure how accurate the authors are in describing the differences.  The key is how they interact with the DOM and memory management; especially if they use identifiers and how they work with garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile. http://jquerymobile.com/

The reason you can't read it is because they are compressing the code which changes around variable names and makes the code as small as possible. This helps the code load faster.

Comment: juqery is used as a plugin , and only need to load when we want to integrate with jquery

Comment: and in sample code that i have downloaded contain no-compress version

Answer (score 1):

Developers typically [minify their javascript](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#MinifyJS) before deployment. This makes it hard to understand. but typically you can go to their website if they are willing to share the code

Comment: i have download example code and have everything with no-compress.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a look at the [github](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe) website of the app.